# Combine two nested dictionaries with same keys but different dictionaries as values

Tags: python, dictionary, dry

I have two dictionaries (see code example) with nested dictionaries as values. I want to join both dictionaires such that I obtain one single dictionary with added key value pairs in the nested dictionairy.

My current code works but it does not seem DRY (don't repeat yourself) to me. What is the most pyhtonic way to solve this problem?

```
dictionary_base = {
  'anton': {
    'name': 'Anton',
    'age': 29,
  },
  'bella': {
    'name': 'Bella',
    'age': 21,
  },
}

dictionary_extension = {
  'anton': {
    'job': 'doctor',
    'address': '12120 New York',
  },
  'bella': {
    'job': 'lawyer',
    'address': '13413 Washington',
  },
}

for person in dictionary_base:
  dictionary_base[person]['job'] = dictionary_extension[person]['job']
  dictionary_base[person]['address'] = dictionary_extension[person]['address']

print(dictionary_base)
```

Desired output should look like

```
{'anton': {'address': '12120 New York',
           'age': 29,
           'job': 'doctor',
           'name': 'Anton'},
 'bella': {'address': '13413 Washington',
           'age': 21,
           'job': 'lawyer',
           'name': 'Bella'}}
```

Comment: what should the result look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dict.update`

**Ex:**

```
dictionary_base = {
  'anton': {
    'name': 'Anton',
    'age': 29,
  },
  'bella': {
    'name': 'Bella',
    'age': 21,
  },
}

dictionary_extenstion = {
  'anton': {
    'job': 'doctor',
    'address': '12120 New York',
  },
  'bella': {
    'job': 'lawyer',
    'address': '13413 Washington',
  },
}

for person in dictionary_base:
    dictionary_base[person].update(dictionary_extenstion[person])

print(dictionary_base)
```

**Output:**

```
{'anton': {'address': '12120 New York',
           'age': 29,
           'job': 'doctor',
           'name': 'Anton'},
 'bella': {'address': '13413 Washington',
           'age': 21,
           'job': 'lawyer',
           'name': 'Bella'}}
```

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was looking for. It would be great if we could simply write ´dictionary_base = dictionary_base + dictionary_extension´, but that is not working :D.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a dictionary comprehension:

```
{k: {**dictionary_base[k], **dictionary_extension[k]} for k in dictionary_base}
```

output:

```
{'anton': {'name': 'Anton',
  'age': 29,
  'job': 'doctor',
  'address': '12120 New York'},
 'bella': {'name': 'Bella',
  'age': 21,
  'job': 'lawyer',
  'address': '13413 Washington'}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, never heard of dictionary comprehension!

Comment: you may have a look over the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)